# Moduli Spaces of Higher Dimensional Complex Tori

Tags: complex-analysis, reference-request, complex-geometry

I know that the space of all complex 1-tori (elliptic curves) is modeled by $SL(2, \mathbb{R})$ acting on the upper half plane. There are many explicit formulas for this action.

Similarly, I have been told that in the higher dimensional cases, the symplectic group $Sp(2n, \mathbb{R})$ acts on some such space to give the moduli space of complex structures on higher dimensional complex tori. Is there a reference that covers this case in detail and gives explicit formulas for the action?

In the 1-dimensional case, all complex tori can be realized as algebraic varieties, but this is not the case for higher dimensional complex tori. Does the action preserve complex structures that come from abelian varieties?

Answer (score 3):

You could check **Complex tori** by *Christina Birkenhake* and *Herbert Lange*, edited by Birkhauser.

In Chapter 7 (Moduli spaces), Section 4 (Moduli spaces of nondegenerate complex tori), Theorems 4.1 and 4.2 should answer you doubts.

Hope it helps.